# Is there a way I can collect all the names and IDs before collecting the scores?

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a way I can gather all the student's names and IDs before getting their grades for each of the assignments?  Currently, my code runs through one student at a time, but is there a way to recall their IDs one at a time to add their grades afterwards?

```
nameID = {}

while input("Would you like to add a student? ") == "yes":
    name = input("What is the student's name?: ")
    ID = input("What is the student's ID?: ")
    nameID[ID] = name   
    scores = []
    assignments = int(input("How many assignments were given? "))

    for i in range(assignments): 
        score = int(input("Enter {}'s score for assignment {} (0-100): ".format(nameID[ID], i+1)))
        scores.append(score)

    average = (sum(scores))/assignments
    print("{}'s average score was {:.1f}".format(name, average))
    nameID[ID] = {"Name": name, "Scores": scores}

print(nameID)
```

Comment: I dont understand the question you're asking. _Why_ do you need to define a dictionary that contains names you haven't defined? Dictionaries don't have indices.

Comment: You're defining a `set`, not a `dict` with `nameID` so `nameID["ID"]` will never work.

Comment: How do you propose you differentiate between scores for each user if you only have one `scores` list?

Comment: You are replacing `name` and `id` in the very next lines.

Comment: Note that `name[0]` is the first letter of the student's name, *not* a reference to the score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to work through some sort of tutorials on Python data types and how to apply them.  It appears that you're trying to build a table of student data, including name, ID, and a list of scores for each student.

This suggests a data frame -- although that data structure is likely beyond what you've learned in class.  In the meantime, it looks like you're trying to use a `dict` to do the job -- this is reasonable.  However, you haven't designed the structure in ways that Python will recognize.

I don't know whether you need to access the data by student name or student ID; your posted code is confused about the relationships.  Assuming that you want to do this by name, perhaps you need a nested dict: name at the upper level, ID and scores underneath.

```
ledger = {}
while input("Would you like to add a student? ") == "yes": 
    name = input("What is the student's name?: ")
    id = input("What is the student's ID?: ")
    ledger[name] = {"ID": id}

assignments = int(input("How many assignments were given? "))

for name in ledger: 
    score_list = []
    for i in range(assignments):
        score = input("Enter {}'s score for assignment {}: ".format(name, i+1))
        score_list.append(int(score))

    ledger[name]["scores"] = {"ID": ID, "scores": scores}
```

Does this move you somewhat down the path to an overall solution?

Comment: This is better than OP's idea. But given ID is more likely to be unique than Name, maybe `ledger` should have `ID` keys.

Comment: That's why I gave the caveat of "assuming" -- a common human will know the student names, but won't have their IDs memorized.  A "proper" implementation would set this up as a class with a data frame, indexed by a unique ID, with a look-up-by-name method.

Comment: Yes I am using the ID as a key, but that is an easy change. Is there any way to do this so that I can add all the students before adding their scores?

Comment: I updated my solution for doing the scores last, in a batch.